# Arduino Uno COM port issue in jupyter python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, arduino-uno

I'm running this code in Jupyter. I am planning to detect data from gas sensor connected to the Arduino for a class project.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import time
     import numpy as np
     import pyfirmata
     import pandas as pd

     x = []
     y = []
     fig = plt.figure()
     dataset, = plt.plot(x, y)
     plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
     plt.ylabel('Signal (V)')
     plt.ion()

     board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM10')
     it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
     it.start()
     AI0 = board.get_pin('a:0:i')
     time.sleep(1)
     starttime = time.time()

     while True:
         if time.time() > starttime + 1200:
             break
         AI0Data = AI0.read()
         runtime = time.time() - starttime
         x.append(runtime)
         y.append(AI0Data)
         dataset.set_xdata(x)
         dataset.set_ydata(y)
         plt.xlim(0, max(x) + 1)
         fig.canvas.draw()
         time.sleep(0.1)

     board.exit()

     dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([x, y]), columns=['Time (s)', 'Signal'])
     dataframe.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

After running this in my Anaconda Jupyter, there's an error showing that some issues with the com port. I changed the com port and modified the com port field in this code but still facing the same issues.

```
     AttributeError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
     Cell In[2], line 15
     12 plt.ylabel('Signal (V)')
     13 plt.ion()
---> 15 board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM10')
     16 it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
     17 it.start()
```

i checked the com port connected to the Arduino from  disk manager. it's the right one (COM 10). Please help. Thnx.